# Zend framework router issue

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, router

I'm having an issue with my routes.

So let's say I have the *TestController* with the action *edit*, that gets a parameter named as 'name'.

The access url would be *test.com/test/edit/name/randomname*.

I wanted to make it so it could be accessed by *test.com/test/edit/randomname*, so I added
this in the function _initRoutes in Bootstrap.

```
$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
            $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                'test/edit/:name',
                array('controller' => 'test', 'action' => 'edit', 'name' => 'Default'));
        $router->addRoute('edit-test', $route);
```

So it works as I want it to, but another issue occurred.
I have a link in the layout.phtml which is something like

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' =>'account','action'=>'logout'));?>">Logout</a>
```

The problem is that when i navigate to *test.com/test/edit/randomname*, the link above for some weird reason changes and points to the same url as above, ie *test.com/test/edit/randomname*.

What's going wrong?

Note: Im using modules, the TestController is in the default module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past, I have had to specify the route to use with the `url()` view-helper. Since your logout route seems to use the default route, specify it in the `url()` invocation:

```
<a href="<?php 
  echo $this->url(array(
     'controller'  =>'account',
     'action'      =>'logout'
  ), 'default'); ?>">Logout</a>
```

If you don't explicity specify the route, then the *current* route gets used, which in your case is probably the `edit-test` route.

Comment: You are right, this solved my problem and thanks for the info on the routing.

Comment: Removed my answer as yours is better. I never really understood why ZF doesn't require both params.

Comment: @TimFountain: Yeah, defaulting to the current route strikes me as odd. Maybe the intention is to accommodate the simplest use-case in which there are no named routes.